# How to set dll search path for a COM server from client?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, com

I am instantiating a COM server using CoCreateInstance(). My COM server loads some dlls dynamically later on. But it fails to find those dlls. One solution to this is to add these paths to PATH env variable, which I want to avoid. I can't set it in code as server is already loaded and it will not honor PATHs set after it is loaded. Best possible solution could be that client should be able to set COM server's search path. Is it possible? How?

Comment: As you already know the path and if you are loading the DLLs using `LoadLibrary` then just use an absolute path.  If you are loading them via COM then they have not been registered properly.

Comment: @RichardCritten, They are non-COM dlls and should be located from search path. I can't use absolute path because it's going to be tedious to find out path of each and every dependent dlls. It will be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: It is excessively unlikely that the client programmer is going to take care of this for you.  In general they don't have the faintest idea where this stuff is located, your installer takes care of it when it registers the server.

Comment: Please clarify whether you are talking about in-process or out-of-process server

Comment: @M.M, this is about out-of-proc server. Had it been in-proc, it would have inherited client's search paths, which is enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the COM server loads the DLLs by name only:

- If the COM server is an in-proc DLL, it is loaded into the client's process, so the client can use `SetDllDirectory()` or `AddDllDirectory()` for itself and the server will include that extra path when loading the DLLs.
- If the COM server is in out-of-proc EXE, the client cannot influence the server's search paths without altering the global `PATH` environment before loading the server, unless the server exposes a COM method that the client can call to let the server alter its own search paths.

  However, if you can put the DLLs in the same folder as the server's EXE, that will be the first place the OS looks for them, then you won't have to mess around with search paths at all.

If you can change the server to load the DLLs by absolute paths, you can then put the DLLs in a folder whose path is relative to the server's installation path, and have the server retrieve its own folder path at runtime (via `GetModuleFileName()`, stripping off the filename) and then append each DLL's relative path+filename to that base installation path.

Or, put the DLLs wherever you want, and store those paths somewhere in your server's internal configuration.

Or, register the DLLs in the Registry so the OS knows where to find them:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\KnownDLLs
```

Comment: I can change the server to load the dlls by absolute paths, but what about dependency chain? I can't find them and load one by one.      
Also, I can't keep the dlls in the folder where server resides due to some constraints. So, for now putting paths in the PATH env variable seems to be the only option.

Comment: @MohanSawant per [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx) on MSDN: "*If a DLL has dependencies, the system searches for the dependent DLLs as if they were loaded with just their module names. This is true even if the first DLL was loaded by specifying a full path.*" Why do you have DLL dependencies scattered all over the place to begin with, instead of having them all in one place? What is preventing the server from using `SetDllDirectory()`/`AddDllDirectory()` to specify the folders where dependencies are looked in?